# Return elements from array, except for repeating

Tags: scala

Write a method that returns the values of all elements in the array, except for repeating. Do not use `for`. - this is task from Scala book.

I tried `myArray.mkString(", ")` but it has duplicates. Searched into Scaladoc but it doesn't help.

Maybe transform it to some kind of Java `Set`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set contains unique value, so use conversion to it:

```
v.toSet.mkString(", ")
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `.distinct`:

```
scala> Array(1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5,4,5,6,7).distinct
res0: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

Calling `.toSet`, as in Michal's answer, works too if you don't care about ordering:

```
scala> Array(1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5,4,5,6,7).toSet
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(5, 1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, using `groupBy` on the identity, which delivers a `Map`, where keys are unique by definition, like this

```
xs.groupBy(identity).keys
```